# How to put 2 different payloads in reducer redux?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, frontend

I have reducer for client aplications. Since, there are two different applications I have to process different payload.

```
export interface CLIENT_STATE_APPLICATION_ONE {
  clientData: ClientData | null;
  application: ApplicationData | null;
  detailedLoan: any;
  customerId: string;
}

export interface CLIENT_STATE_APPLICATION_TWO {
  clientData: ClientData | null;
  application: EntityInstance | null;
  detailedLoan: any;
  customerId: string;
}

const initialValues = {
  clientData: null,
  application: null,
  detailedLoan: null,
  customerId: '',
};

export default function(state = initialValues, action: {type: CLIENT_ACTIONS,
  payload: Pick<CLIENT_STATE_APPLICATION_ONE, 'clientData' | 'application'  | 'customerId'>}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CLIENT_ACTIONS.SET_CLIENT_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        clientData: action.payload
      };
    case CLIENT_ACTIONS.SET_CLIENT_APPLICATION:
      return {
        ...state,
        application: action.payload,
      };
    case CLIENT_ACTIONS.SET_CUSTOMER_ID:
      return {
        ...state,
        customerId: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

how to make it for second payload? I want to make it for second type of application as well. Now it works only for first one.

Comment: It looks like you are setting the entire payload object to each property: `customerId: action.payload`

Comment: But to answer your question, you could use different `action.type` values for each application, you could add an extra property in the payload for `applicationType`, or you could figure out what type it is at runtime by examining the values.